# Bigquery merge and de-duplicate column of comma separated numbers

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a column with comma separated numbers. I want to merge and de-duplicate the values so each value only appears once.

| numbers |
| --- |
| 123, 983 |
| 983, 482 |

The desired output from above would be 123, 983, 482. Whats the best way to do this in bigquery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can consider below.

```sql
WITH sample_table AS (
  SELECT '123, 983' numbers UNION ALL
  SELECT '983, 483'
)
SELECT STRING_AGG(DISTINCT number, ', ') merged 
  FROM sample_table, UNNEST(SPLIT(numbers, ', ')) number
```

**Query results**

[image]

- [STRING_AGG()](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/aggregate_functions#string_agg)